# How to make menu items span across menu bar evenly

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a site that I am working on.. and would like to know how to span the menu items evenly across the menu bar.

I know how to do it technically, but I want to make sure it's correct.

I want to be able to add another menu item and still have it look normal or overflow properly, etc.

The site is http://phillysuburbanhomes.com

---

Okay, so I added

```
.wpsight-menu li {
    width:14%;
    text-align:center
}
```

(more menu items were added)

My issue now is, that the full menu item doesn't show now

http://phillysubrubanhome.com - you can see what it's doing live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I combined one of your methods with this this and it worked:

```
.wpsight-menu li {
    width:14%;
    text-align:center
}

.wpsight-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to give your anchors (`a`) the same padding and margins on the left and right and a percentage width of the `li`, like this;

```
ul#main-menu {
   width: 100%;
}

ul#main-menu li {
   width: 20%; /* for 5 menu items */
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   display: inline-block;
}

ul#main-menu li a {
   padding: 0px 5px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   display: block;
}
```

and change the width of the `li` depending on the number of menu items.

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are 5 menu items, im assuming you would be adding another menu item thus making it 6 menu items.

The width of the container is 980px. Divide it in 6 parts which comes to 163.33. We need to give the width in percentage i.e 16.66%.

Set the width for each li as 16.66% and center-align the text.

Your css would be as follows:

```
ul#main-menu li{
    width:16.66%;
    text-align:center
}
```